# How to view download progress while Finder downloads new iOS version?

Tags: macos, finder, catalina

In macOS Catalina, the iOS devices are synced and updated using the Finder instead of iTunes.

Is there a way to see the progress of the iOS-download in Finder?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no immediate way.

But see this article: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/250790312

> While there is no progress bar available, one potential way to estimate the progress is through Terminal, with the following command:
>
> ```
> ls -lhrt ~/Library/iTunes/iPhone\ Software\ Updates
> ```
>
> It will show the size of the current (*.ipsw.download) and all previous (*.ipsw) update files, which can be used to estimate progress. For example, for a 2.9G update file (can be estimated using previous update files), if we see that the current update file size is 2.3G, then the progress would be approximately 2.3G / 2.9G = 79%. By running the above command periodically, we can somewhat know how long it may still take (or at least the downloading is still in progress and not stopped because of network or other issue).

Comment: Maybe even use `watch ls -lhrt ~/Library/iTunes` to catch the iPad update file too and refresh the size ? Btw `watch` can be installed with `brew install watch`

Comment: For ipad use this command: `ls -lhrt ~/Library/iTunes/iPad\ Software\ Updates`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Joe Farina's answer, you can also get a *rough* idea of how quickly things are progressing from Activity Monitor's Network tab.

Look for AMPDevicesAgent, which should show you how much that process has downloaded so far. This is *probably* ** (but not guaranteed) how much of the latest update you're downloading has downloaded.

[image: AMPDevicesAgent]

If you're not downloading lots of other things, you can also see the speed of your download at the bottom of the activity monitor (in blue in the image below).

[image]

** Note that this is actually the total downloaded by that process, so if you're downloading multiple updates or have recently downloaded an update, that will be included in this number.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use the terminal. The following code shows you the file download progress and also automatically clears the terminal screen and shows you the recent file size downloaded.

```
while true
do
clear
ls -lhrt ~/Library/iTunes/iPhone\ Software\ Updates
sleep 20
done
```

The "clear" command simple clears your terminal screen so you only see the latest row / value.

The numeric value after they keyword "sleep" is the number of seconds the code sleep before repeating itself again. So a value of 20 (20 secs) means, the same ls -lhrt command gets repeated after 20 seconds and shows you the most recent downloaded side of the file. So you do not have to repeatedly type the command again and again.